# share data between two separated applications in iPhone

Tags: iphone

I'm developing two separated applications but there is a `plist` file for one of those app contains data that I need it on the other one.

is there is any way to get data? in case yes please show me some sample code? what about the `NSUserDefault` could it be useful?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

NSUserDefault will not work. You need to create a custom URL scheme for your app and then you will be able to pass some data to your another app.

follow these url's you will find what you want.

http://www.tutoplanet.com/android-tutorials/ios-sdk-working-with-url-schemes/

http://iosdevelopertips.com/cocoa/launching-your-own-application-via-a-custom-url-scheme.html

Answer (score 0):

`NSUserDefaults` will not help you at all. Your applications are each sandboxed separately and have access to very little other than their own data.

You can, however, open a file from one app in another. You can see more about that [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2202806/passing-a-file-to-another-iphone-application).

Other Resources

1. [Apple Approved iPhone Inter-process Communication](http://www.mobileorchard.com/apple-approved-iphone-inter-process-communication/)
2. [2-way app integration on the iPhone: How it works](http://blog.innerfence.com/2009/01/05/2-way-app-integration-on-the-iphone-how-it-works/)